# importing .vpl files (vpn tunnels) on mac

Tags: vpn, import, tunnel

Is there any way I can import a .vpl file? This is the only way of connecting I have and for now I can only do it on Windows (with FortiClient 4.x.x) because 5 doesn't support importing .vpl anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ["FortiClientTools"](ftp://pftpintl:F0rt1intl@support.fortinet.com/FortiClient/Windows/v4.00/4.0MR3/MR3_Patch_5/FortiClientTools_4.3.5.0472.zip) application in Windows to [import](http://kb.fortinet.com/kb/viewContent.do?externalId=FD30861) your `.vpl` configuration file. From there, you can export the configuration file to a newer type (4.3/5.0) that can be imported into newer versions of FortiClient. Exported config files that are encrypted will likely have a filename extension of `.sconn`; unencrypted config files should be appended with `.conn`.

If you need to import those config files into the newest version (5.2) of FortiClient, you can change the filename extension from `.sconn` or `.conn` to the newer format (`.sconf`; `.conf`). Once the extension has been changed, you can import that config file under the FortiClient menu -> Preferences -> General -> Restore.